# Match Lone Set of Empty (or space-filled) Parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

While this may be a trivial question, I am stretched as how to resolve this so far, so thanks for the help in advance!

I would like to match on a set of brackets not containing any parameters in a given string. Unless the set of brackets starts with characters. These are my scenarios.

Valid Scenarios:

- "()"
- "(   )"
- " ()"
- "() "
- " ( ) "
- "abc ()"

Invalid Scenarios:

- "abc()"

So far my regex is

```
\s*\(\s*\)\s*
```

This gets all instances obviously getting abc() as well.
Anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zM6xO7/1 ?

Comment: Ahhh a look behind! Thanks @zerkms for the link that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?<!\S)\(\s*\)
```

See what matches and fails in **[the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/xL7pG5/1)**.

**Explanation**

- The negative lookbehind asserts that what precedes is not a non-whitespace character
- `\(\s*\)` matches your brackets with optional spaces

**Reference**

- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

@zerkms resolved this for me with a positive look behind.

```
(?<=^|\s)\(\s*\)
```

Thanks!